# efibootmgr output is not clear (incomplete)

Tags: grub2, uefi, surface

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04.1 in my surface pro. During installation i encountered a few problem with uefi. Now i'm trying to fix the boot process but efibootmgr gives me incomplete output:

```
root@carlo-surface-ubuntu:/home/carlo# efibootmgr 
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0000,0000,0000,0000,0000
```

It does not list what is associated to each number.
Doing

```
efibootmgr -v
```

doesn't change anything.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First, [File a bug report.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) Be sure to include detailed information about your computer, including firmware information (obtainable on the first few lines of `dmesg` output, in most cases) and the *exact* brand and model of your computer.

Second, until the bug is fixed, you may need to use something else. Unfortunately, AFAIK `efibootmgr` is it for Linux, but you can use something like `bcfg` in an EFI shell. (See [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#bcfg) for some basic information on `bcfg`.)